# How to get parameter value for a drop down list?

Tags: java, liferay

I created adrop down list as follows:-

```
Teacher Name: <select name="teacher" >
        <c:forEach var="currTeacher" items="${listTeacher}">
            <option value="${currTeacher.teacherId}">${currTeacher.teacherName}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

The snapshot for drop down list is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nKcw.png)

I am retrieving its value as `String teacherName=(String) actionRequest.getParameter("teacher");`

But when I am printing value of teacherName, it is printing null. So what could be the problem?I want to tell that I submitted the form successfully and on submission I am calling the method `addStudent()`Inside `addStudent()` I am retrieving the parameter as shown above.Please help. Thanx in advance.

The code for `addStudent()` is as follows:-

```
public void addStudent(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException,SystemException {
        try {
            System.out.println("Student : "+StudentLocalServiceUtil.getStudentByGenderMale());
            String firstName = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "firstName");
            String lastName = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "lastName");
            int studentAge = ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "studentAge");
            int studentGender = ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "sex", 1);
            String address = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "address");
            String teacherName=(String) actionRequest.getParameter("teacher");
            System.out.println("teacher name " + teacherName);
            // add student record
            // create primary key
            long studentId = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment();
            // create student persistance object
            Student student = null;
            student = StudentLocalServiceUtil.createStudent(studentId);
            // fill the data in persistance object
            student.setFirstName(firstName);
            student.setLastName(lastName);
            student.setStudentAge(studentAge);
            student.setStudentGender(studentGender);
            student.setStudentAddress(address);
            // Add student persistance object to database student table
            student = StudentLocalServiceUtil.addStudent(student);
            if (student != null) {
                // adding success message
                SessionMessages.add(actionRequest.getPortletSession(),
                        "student-add-success");
                _log.info("Student have been added successfylly");
            } else {
                SessionErrors.add(actionRequest.getPortletSession(),
                        "student-add-error");
                _log.error("There is an Erron in adding Student");
            }
            // navigate to add student jsp page
            actionResponse.setRenderParameter("mvcPath",
                    "/html/jsps/add_student.jsp");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            SessionErrors.add(actionRequest.getPortletSession(),
                    "student-add-error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the code for addStudent() method

Comment: Could you show the code for 'ParamUtil' class

Comment: ParamUtil class is the in-built class..It is well tested so no chances of error there..the code of ParamUtil is very lengthy. You can see the code yourselves from the `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil` package which is the inbuilt package provided by Liferay..Thanx in advance

Comment: @AbhishekJain Using developer tools of the browser check for the value of `<option value="${currTeacher.teacherId}">`. Do you have corresponding Id's there?!

Answer (score 3):

I had observed similar type of issue, while migrating a legacy portlet to Liferay 6.2

> From Liferay 6.2, portlet action class will only consider those request
>   parameters which have appended portlet namespace with them. This is
>   default behavior of Liferay 6.2 portlet action class. [***more...***](https://web.liferay.com/web/meera.success/blog/-/blogs/liferay-requires-name-spaced-parameters)

There are three possible solutions to this problem:

1. Migrate your sample HTML form fields to AUI, which automatically appends portlet namespace at its own.
2. Use sample HTML form fields and manually append portlet namespace to it using `<portlet:namespace/>` or `renderResponse.getNamespace()`.
3. Use sample HTML form fields and set `<requires-namespaced-parameters>` to `false` in `liferay-portlet.xml`.

Comment: Parkash, could you please tell me what Abhishek did to solve the problem?

Comment: Abhishek change his sample HTML form fields to AUI fields. Rather than this, you can just set `<requires-namespaced-parameters>` to `false` in your portlet's `liferay-portlet.xml`, would also resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution..I just used alloy ui to create form and I got the parameter value which I passed during form submission.

Comment: The problem is that you just got the solution only by changing whole form to AUI but didn't understand what was actually causing the issue. While, this could have been resolved by just changing one property with existing sample HTML form.